# Group theory of tensor products of the harmonic oscillator

Tags: quantum-mechanics, angular-momentum, harmonic-oscillator, group-theory, identical-particles

I learned that the symmetry group of the quantum isotropic harmonic oscillator in n-dimensions is $SU(n)$. Specifically, in two-dimensions, it is $SU(2)$ and hence the eigenstates are given by the irreducible representations of $SU(2)$. Sticking to the usual notation for angular momentum in physics, we can label the eigenstates by $|l,m>$, where $m=-l, -l+1,..., l$ and $l$ runs over non-negative half integers. Here each $l$ gives a different irreducible representation with dimension $2l+1$. This is precisely the degeneracy of the $l$-th harmonic oscillator shell, with energy $\hbar\omega(2l+1)$. Furthermore, the angular momentum in z-direction is given by $2\hbar m$.

So far, so good. Now I could form tensor products of the different representations if I'm interested in describing multiple particles inside the harmonic oscillator. For non-interacting particles the tensor product $V_{l_1}\otimes V_{l_2}$ is a subspace of the eigenspace of the combined Hamiltonian with energy $2\hbar\omega(l_1+l_2+1)$.
On the other hand, I can decompose this thensor product representation into irreducible reps in the standard way,

$V_{l_1}\otimes V_{l_2} = \bigoplus_{L=|l_1-l_2|}^{l_1+l_2} V_L.$

However, these $V_L$ now seem to play a very different role, as the energy of the system is apparently not given by $\hbar\omega(2L+1)$. So what is the proper interpretation of the $|L,M>$?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean..

Comment: Sorry, but I can't follow you? If I compose two spin 1/2 particles I'll get a spin 0 singlet or a spin 1 triplet.. Why would the singlet have ground state energy (corresponding to no excitations in any direction of the oscillator for neither particle)

Comment: Please, maybe this would help me out

Comment: While anything with $SU(2)$ symmetry can be labeled by $l,m$, the fact that there is only one subspace for every $l$ is kind of coincidental. You can, in principle, construct systems with $SU(2)$ symmetry where not every $l$ is present (for example, most spherically symmetric potentials are essentially $SO(3)$ plus a phase), or where some $l$'s occur multiple times. Is that what this is asking about?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to understand the language of the [Jordan-Schwinger realization of angular momentum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jordan_map#The_example_of_angular_momentum).  You must understand that throughout there are only *two* different oscillators, not more, even when you "add angular momenta" by tensoring states. If, somehow, bizarrely, you changed your Hilbert space, you'd have more oscillators, instead, and *su(n)* instead of *su(2)*! But you don't. Call the oscillators *a* and *b*.
$$
H/\hbar\omega= 1 + a^\dagger a + b^\dagger b ,\\
L_z=(a^\dagger a - b^\dagger b)/2 , ~~L_+ = a^\dagger b , ~~~L_-= b^\dagger a,\\
a^{\dagger ~k} b^{\dagger ~n}|0\rangle \equiv |k;n\rangle . 
$$
You then have
$$
E=1+ k+n, ~~~L_z |k;n\rangle={k-n\over 2}|k;n\rangle\equiv m |k;n\rangle,   \\ L^2|k;n\rangle = {k+n\over 2} \left ({k+n\over 2}  +1\right )|k;n\rangle \equiv l(l+1)    |k;n\rangle \leadsto\\
k=l+m, ~~~ n= l-m.
$$

So the doublet representation is
$$
|\uparrow\rangle =|1;0\rangle,  ~~~(m=1/2, l=1/2)\\
|\downarrow\rangle =|0;1\rangle,  ~~~(m=-1/2, l=1/2)\\
E=1+1,
$$
the first excited state.

Tensor two ups. This is the state
$$
|\uparrow \uparrow\rangle= |2;0\rangle ~~\implies l=1, m=1, E=1+2.
$$
Apply the lowering operator to it, to get
$$
{|\uparrow\downarrow\rangle  +|\downarrow\uparrow\rangle \over \sqrt{2}}=|1;1\rangle ~~\implies l=1, m=0, E=1+2,
$$
and further
$$
|\downarrow \downarrow\rangle= |2;0\rangle ~~\implies l=1, m=-1, E=1+2,
$$
the three second excited states.

It is evident that, for any $l$, the $m=0$ states require $k=n$. So the state orthogonal to the middle state above *must* be
the
$$
{|\uparrow\downarrow\rangle  -|\downarrow\uparrow\rangle \over \sqrt{2}}=|0;0\rangle=|0\rangle ~~\implies l=0, m=0, E=1,
$$
the ground state! But it's inaccessible to tensoring: you cannot combine two excitations to drop to the ground state,

The reason is the oscillators *commute among themselves*, and so you only get  the symmetric representation in the composition, and you project out all others. (To get the above singlet, you'd need **fermion** oscillators, antisymmetrizing the two tensor factors.) So the only surviving factor in your (last) "Clebsch reduction" direct sum formula is the symmetric rep, $L=l_1+l_2$. There are no other *L*s to consider.

---

***Edit post comments***

It appears the question was about the 4-dimensional isotropic oscillator, after all, whose symmetry group is SU(4) with 15 symmetry generators, not just 3! The energy/$\hbar \omega$ is then
$4/2 + n$, where $n\equiv n_1+n_2+n_3+n_4$, the sum of the occupation numbers of all 4 uncoupled oscillators.

The degeneracy for a given energy shell characterized by *n*, above, is the dimensionality of the symmetric representation of SU(4) with *n* boxes in the Young tableau
(so, arrayed next to each other),
$$
{4+n-1 \choose n}= \frac{(n+3)(n+2) (n+1)}{3!}  ~~,
$$
hence 4,10,20,... for *n*=1,2,3,...  Check this.

Comment: But if we considered two particles, the Hamiltonian of both particles would actually consist of four uncoupled harmonic oscillators, right?

Comment: I have no idea what you are saying. 4 uncoupled oscillators' symmetry is su(4), *not* su(2)!  What is a particle beyond an occupation number? My answer above assumes two types of oscillators throughout. Not 4.

Comment: Yes, there seems to be a misunderstanding I'm afraid. I'm interested in the case where two particles are placed in the harmonic oscillator, which would in my opinion give rise to four oscillator modes (2 per particle) with corresponding annihilation operators $a_1, a_2, b_1, b_2$. Basically like you wrote above. To my understanding these operators annihilate quanta and not particles, so they're different from the ann. operators in field theory (please correct me if I'm wrong). One consequence of having two particles is that the ground state energy is now $2\hbar\omega$.

Comment: To construct the spectrum of the combined system one usually looks at the tensor product space of the two one-particle Hamiltonians. Since the particles don't interact eigenstates of the full system are directly given by product states, where the energy of each one-particle state just needs to be added (which leads to the formula 2ℏ(1+2+1) in my question).  This brings me back to my original question on the meaning of the decomposition in irreducible reps of the product states

Comment: That's all fine, but then you should talk about a 4-d oscillator, which is straightforward, and has little to do with su(2). Its symmetry group is su(4), and using angular momentum  is off, off the mark... You have vastly expanded your symmetry group. Read further up in WP.

Comment: So you say the decomposition of $V_{l_1}\otimes V_{l_2}$ into irreps of $SU(2)$ is useless in this context?

Comment: Aggressively useless. There are 12 more symmetry generators!!! I could summarize the basics of the 4-d oscillator if requested.

Comment: I'd appreciate that thank's a lot already!