# Is there a relationship between the degeneracy of the Hamiltonian and the set of non-commuting operators that commute with the Hamiltonian?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators, hamiltonian, commutator, ground-state

I'd like to know if there is any relationship between the number of the degeneracy of the Hamiltonian and the set of non-commuting operators that commute with the Hamiltonian.

If I know a set of $n$ independent non-commuting operators, how do I know if that set is complete to characterise the whole ket space of the Hamiltonian?

Knowing that the set is complete, is there any relationship between $n$ and the number of the degeneracy?

Comment: How did you define *d=3* degeneracy?

Comment: @CosmasZachos It's an example. I'm asking if there is a general rule.

Comment: Do these operators close into a Lie algebra? The ground state is non-degenerate for linearly realized symmetries. [Linked](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/694506/group-theory-of-tensor-products-of-the-harmonic-oscillator) and [also](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/574689/degeneracy-of-the-ground-state-of-harmonic-oscillator).

Comment: Suppose the non-commuting operators form some sort of closed algebra under multiplication, then the ground state subspace must give a representation of this algebra.